# Polynomial = 0 on edges of tesseract?

Tags: polynomials, analytic-geometry, polytopes

Can there exist a polynomial on $w,x,y,z$ whose value is zero on the edges of a tesseract – or rather, on the projection of those edges to the unit sphere – and nonzero everywhere else on the unit sphere?

The dual's vertex figure has central symmetry, so its edges form great circles, leading to a simple answer: $(w^2+x^2) (w^2+y^2) (w^2+z^2) (x^2+y^2) (x^2+z^2) (y^2+z^2)$.
That's not true of the tesseract: the great circles that include its edges also include each cell's major diagonals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, it can't**. Not even in 3D.

Imagine a polynomial in several variables (we don't really care how many). Imagine also a straight line in its domain. A line can be parameterized, say, as $\vec a+\vec b\cdot t$, where $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are constant vectors and $t$ is some real number. What are the values of our polynomial along this line? That would be some function of $t$. What kind of function? A polynomial, too. Can this function be zero on some *interval*, and then cease to be zero? No, polynomials can't behave like that; if it is 0 on some interval, it is 0 everywhere, that is, on the whole line.

Same goes for the great circles, except that it would be a *trig polynomial* in this case. The rest is the same: it can only have so many roots, and once 
it has more, it is a constant 0 all the way around the great circle.

So that's why polynomials (or analytic functions in general, for that matter) are unfit for the task.